# Как передать список ListView в DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, dialogfragment

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно передать ListView со списком Блютуз в DialodFragment, создание списка в layout работает корректно? но вот в Fragment открывается пустой прямоугольник без писка

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> pairedDeviceArrayList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDeviceAdapter;
public static BluetoothSocket clientSocket;

private ImageView btnImageBluetooth;

DialogFragment bltDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_device);

    btnImageBluetooth = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnImageBluetooth);
    btnImageBluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //myDialogFragment.show(manager, "dialog");

            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            myDialogFragment.show(transaction, "dialog");



            if (permissionGranted()) {

                bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (bluetoothEnabled()) {
                    findBluetooth(); 

                }
            }

        }
    });
}


private boolean bluetoothEnabled() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean permissionGranted() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
            == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, 0);
        return false;
    }
}


public void findBluetooth() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) {
        pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {

            pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device.getAddress() + "/" + device.getName());
        }







        pairedDeviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.item_device, R.id.item_device_textView, pairedDeviceArrayList);


        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);





        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                final String itemMAC = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().split("/", 2)[0];

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(itemMAC);
                        try {


                            BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord
                                    (device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                            socket.connect();
                            if (socket.isConnected()) {

                                Log.e("eee", "socket get");
                                clientSocket = socket;

                            } else {

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }.start();

            }
        });
    }
}
 }
```

---

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


ListView listView;


@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//  MainActivity ;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
   // builder.setView(R.id.list_device);
    builder.setTitle("Выберите ")
            .setItems(R.layout.item_device, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Передать виджет вряд ли получится в диалог. Но вот передать массив устройств можно. Для этого нужно в процессе вывода диалога в этом месте:

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
myDialogFragment.show(transaction, "dialog");
```

добавить bundle который будет использоваться для передачи данных:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("devices_list", pairedDeviceArrayList);
```

по итогу будет выглядеть так:

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("devices_list", pairedDeviceArrayList);
myDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle)
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
myDialogFragment.show(transaction, "dialog");
```

и дальше получения массива в диалоге делается так:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    arrayList= getArguments().getStringArrayList("devices_list");
    ...
}
```

так же не забудьте что нужно будет сделать глобальную переменную в диалоге чтобы можно было ее потом использовать. Таким образом вы передадите данные в ваш диалог, и потом уже их можно будет отобразить в списке который добавляется через xml так же как и в активности. Если же вы хотите передавать список устройств `bluetooth` то нужно сделать глобальную переменную в активности которая будет соответствовать вашему массиву устройств и дальше ее передавать:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("devices_list", devicesList);
```

Так как сейчас код выше будет передавать массив строк и все. Поэтому если вам нужно будет что-то делать с элементами массива например подключится к устройству, то стоит передавать массив устройств а не строк.